# EditText not resize based on content in a viewpager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-constraintlayout

I have a simple structure. MainActivity with BottomNavigationView and NavController. In this nav controller, i have 4 items. One of them is FavoritesFragment. This fragment has simple layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context=".view.main.favorites.FavoritesFragment">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/vpTest"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tlTest"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With following code:

FragmentAdapter

```kotlin
package com.lust.ahri.view.main.favorites

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
import com.lust.ahri.view.base.BaseFragment

class TestAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragmentManager, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) {

    private val fragments: MutableList<BaseFragment> = mutableListOf()
    private val titles: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return fragments[position]
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return fragments.count()
    }

    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return titles[position]
    }

    fun addFragment(fragment: BaseFragment, title: String) {
        fragments.add(fragment)
        titles.add(title)
    }
}
```

And FavoritesFragment

```kotlin
class FavoritesFragment : BaseFragment() {


    private lateinit var adapter: TestAdapter

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_favorites, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        adapter = TestAdapter(childFragmentManager)
        adapter.addFragment(TestFragment(), "Test1")
        adapter.addFragment(TestFragment(), "Test2")
        vpTest.adapter = adapter
        tlTest.setupWithViewPager(vpTest)
    }
}
```

Problem that in my TestFragment i have layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:hint="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

    <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:hint="10"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I meant that my edit texts will resize with wrap_content like as usual depending on the number of characters, in fact, the fields do not change their size but are only cropped.

I tried to change my layout to Constraint, Relative or another, but actually i couldn't find any solution.

I need an answer how to make edit texts change their width in a viewpager like a default layout behaviour and why it's happening.

Comment: I will suggest you not to use a fixed dp height. Can you show me your screenshot too?

Comment: With wrap_content on height not work too... 
Photo of UI https://imgur.com/1sXWTMt

Comment: its because you have set 0dp height for the Viewpager.

Comment: I have posted a code in the answer below. Let me know if that solves your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem lies in the ViewPager 0dp height. Try this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/mtab_ID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorAccent1"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="3dp"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/colorWhite"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/mViewpager_ID"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
         />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah as I said in the answer, the problem lies in the 0dp height which was making your view act that way.